# Trying to connect my Raspberry Pi Localhost

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi

I'm making a flask website on my Raspberry Pi (3B +).
I creating my application through my PC by an ssh connection to the RPI (MobaXTerm on address 192.XXX.X.XX).

I set up my application to run on a special port on the localhost -> localhost:port.
From another RPI terminal, I can make a curl request to it, and got the right answer.
But, I'm trying to access the webpage through my computer (192.XXX.X.XX:port) but it doesn't work.

Can you help me ? :)

Comment: Did you try starting your Flask app on `0.0.0.0` rather than `localhost`?

Comment: Hum, I started it on 127.0.0.1

Comment: Ok, you have right, I didn't set, the right hostname. Thanks :)

Comment: Remember that any address in the `127.0.0.0/8` address block cannot eve be used on any network anywhere. You cannot use that addressing outside your host, as either source or destination address.